# How to restrict access for module in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way in Node to restrict access or only allow access to certain other modules from a specific module?
Should I replace the `require` function and the `require` object in the global scope?
I am basically not trusting a specific module. It might have malicious code, and I want to protect my server from it. The idea is similar to Java policies where you can restrict access based on namespace.

Edit: I found a way to do this and published the solution as require-shield on npmjs.org. https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-shield

Comment: Maybe you could just not use that specific module.

Comment: What TGrif said. Why would you use a module that you don't trust and then try to invent some convoluted way of NOT allowing yourself to use it?

Comment: By definition I do not trust a module I did not write myself... I want a way to safeguard my server from malicious code that is more automated that having to manually review the code in each required module

Comment: I am also looking for a way to run user provided code safely

Comment: @gforce301, there are good reasons why you might want to limit the import of a module. For example, you write some helper functions that you don't want to be used anywhere else in a shared codebase other than where you intend to import them. You want to make it clear in the export for your coworkers that they should not attempt to use this module. Maybe you just don't want to maintain the functions, or maybe they only work well within one specific context.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way in Node to restrict access or only allow access to certain other modules from a specific module?

No. There is not.

> Should I replace the require function and the require object in the global scope?

That won't prevent access.  Any rogue code can still use `fs.readFile()` and `eval()` to run any external code they want.

> I am basically not trusting a specific module. It might have malicious code, and I want to protect my server from it.

The only way to begin to protect your server from malicious code is to run it in an external process and very carefully control what that external process has privileges to do (e.g. put it in its own user account that has only basic privileges).  The safest way is to run the untrusted code in a VM that is completely sandboxed from the rest of your server.

There is also [node.js VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) which runs code in a different instance of Javascript so the external code cannot muck with your server's Javascript environment.  While this does protect your Javascript code from the other Javascript code, it does not provide the full system protection that running the external code in an actual VM would provide (e.g. the untrusted code still has access to your file system and other system resources).

Comment: I could make a modification to the `require` object and function to disallow requiring `fs` for instance.

Comment: @4thex -  There's all sorts of ways around that.  For example, they could just start up a new instance of node.js as a child_process and run their code there and you wouldn't have any control over that instance.  Or, they could download a native code module that would implement their own access to the file system.  And, those two options are with only a minute or so of thinking about it.  node.js has a wide API that can do pretty much anything.  It is simply not designed for controlling untrusted code.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem like you can use `fs` without requiring it first. That would eliminate the `fs.readFile()` risk you are mentioning if I replace the `require` function in the global scope.

Comment: In my replaced `require`, I can disallow `child_process`, `fs`, and any other module I don't like.

Comment: @4thex - How did you replace `require()`?  It is not as simple as just reassigning it.  Every module is passed a different `require()`.

Comment: take a look at the source code of require-shield. If my module is required first, every subsequent require will call my replaced localRequire function.

Comment: @4thex - Does it matter to you that code that wants to can defeat that in a matter of minutes?

Comment: Please submit an issue to the GitHub repository with steps to reproduce, and I will take a look. I am interested in hardening this code.

Comment: @4thex - The usual reason for hooking `replace()` is to offer new functionality for things like webPack for code that follows the normal rules, not to prevent what you're trying to prevent.  For the first way I could see around it, just look at the implementation here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L606.

Comment: @4thex - In case that wasn't clear enough, all it takes is this: `const fs = module.constructor._load('fs');`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in Node to restrict access or only allow access to certain other modules from a specific module?

Node.js v20 shipped with an experimental [permission model](https://nodejs.org/api/permissions.html) that can do quite close to what you want to do. If you run the script with the  `--experimental-permission` option:

```
node --experimental-permission index.js
```

It will prevent all file system access, and you can use the `--allow-fs-read` and `--allow-fs-write` flags to allow access to a specific directory or file. For example:

```
node --experimental-permission --allow-fs-write=/tmp/ index.js
```

The `--allow-fs-write=/tmp/` will allow your program to only access the `/tmp/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Also Believer on Offline system is safer, so isolate the Javascript process with container/virtualization would be the next closer thing you want.

If you really want to dive into Javascript possibilities, there is also [node vm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2), that claim it can run untrusted code than official Node.js VM.